# MYSQL find difference form two count columns in a sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is

```
SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
 visits_planned, t2.actual_visits
    FROM s_day_plan t1
    LEFT JOIN(
        select doctor_id,date_of_visit, count(*) as actual_visits
        FROM s_doctor_visits
        where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
        group by date(date_of_visit) 
    ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
GROUP BY t1.date
```

I getting the correct results as below:
[image]

Now my requirement is to get the difference of visits_planned - actual_visits

when I put in this line: `(visits_planned - t2.actual_visits) as difference` gives the error : Unknown column `t1.visits_planned`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

t1.visit_planned isn't a real column of table t1, that's just a label you use to name the count. If you want to do it, you could do

```
 select plan_date, representative_id,visits_planned,actual_visits,
 (visits_planned - actual_visits) as difference
 from (
 SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
  visits_planned, t2.actual_visits
  FROM s_day_plan t1
  LEFT JOIN(
    select doctor_id,date_of_visit, count(*) as actual_visits
    FROM s_doctor_visits
    where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
    group by date(date_of_visit) 
    ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
   WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
    GROUP BY t1.date) as tab
```

OR create a view with your query and select from there like

```
 create view myviewname as
 SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
 visits_planned, t2.actual_visits
 FROM s_day_plan t1
 LEFT JOIN(
    select doctor_id,date_of_visit, count(*) as actual_visits
    FROM s_doctor_visits
    where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
    group by date(date_of_visit) 
    ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
   WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
   GROUP BY t1.date
 -----
select plan_date, representative_id,visits_planned,actual_visits,
 (visits_planned - actual_visits) as difference
 from myviewname
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason being visits_planned is a derived column and not available in columns listing:

```
   SELECT plan_date, (visits_planned-actual_visits) sub_col
   from(
     SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
       visits_planned, t2.actual_visits
        FROM s_day_plan t1
        LEFT JOIN(
            select doctor_id,date_of_visit, count(*) as actual_visits
            FROM s_doctor_visits
            where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
            group by date(date_of_visit) 
        ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
      WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
      GROUP BY t1.date
   ) t
```

making it derived table make all derived columns be available in the listing.

Comment: I get: 
Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION t2.actual_visits does not exist 0.000 sec

Comment: Sorry my bad `t2.actual_visits` table t2 no longer available, new table is `t`

Answer (score 0):

Create variable instead of (as actual_visits)

```
 SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
 visits_planned, count(*) -@var1
 FROM s_day_plan t1
 LEFT JOIN(
    select doctor_id,date_of_visit, @var1 := count(*) 
    FROM s_doctor_visits
    where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
    group by date(date_of_visit) 
 ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
 WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
 GROUP BY t1.date
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT t1.date as plan_date, t1.representative_id, count(*) as 
 visits_planned, t2.actual_visits, count(*) -  t2.actual_visits AS your_difference_answer
    FROM s_day_plan t1
    LEFT JOIN(
        select doctor_id,date_of_visit, count(*) as actual_visits
        FROM s_doctor_visits
        where deleted = 0 and user_id = 2 and item_master_id <> 1
        group by date(date_of_visit) 
    ) as t2 on(date(t2.date_of_visit) = t1.date)
WHERE t1.deleted = 0 AND t1.created_by = 2
GROUP BY t1.date`

You need to do this as `vivsits_planned` is derived colum and not existing in table. Once you give real colum `count(*)` MySQL understand what you are trying to do